# Pop-up form that has JS progress bar after submit then progress bar runs to 50% and gives user error and refer them to contact us

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a pop up form that has a javascript progress bar after submit then the progress bar runs to 50% and gives the user an error and refers them to contact us in the pop up. I'm running into an error though, please help.

**Here is my javascript progress bar:**

```html
 <style>
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 50) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here is my pop up code for html form fill:**

```html
<!-- body starts here -->
 <body id ="bdy" style="overflow:hidden;">
 
 <div id="abc">
 
  <!-- Popup div starts here -->
 <div id="popupContact"> 

 <!-- contact us form -->
  <form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
   <img src="images/3.png" id="close" onclick ="div_hide()" />
   <h2>Transfer Details</h2><hr/>
   
   
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Reciever's information:</legend>
    
 Account Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Account number" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" value="" id="name" placeholder="Account Number"><br>
    
 Account Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Account Name" value="" id="name" placeholder="Account Name"><br><br>
 
 Routing (ABA):<br>
<input type="text" name="Routing (ABA)" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" id="name" value="" placeholder="Routing (ABA)"><br><br>
 
 Bank Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="Bank Name" id="name"  value="" placeholder="Bank Name"><br><br>
 
 Account Type:<br>
 <select name="Account Type" placeholder="Account Type">
                            <option>Fix Deposit</option>
                            <option>Checking</option>
                            <option>Savings</option>
                            <option>Current</option>
                        </select>
    
  </fieldset>
  
 <a id="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()" onclick="move()">Send</a>
   
   <p><span>Note :</span> All Form Is Required.</p>
   
  
  </form>
 </div> 
 <!-- Popup div ends here -->
 </div>
 <!-- display popup button -->
    <CENTER><h1>Transfer To Another Account:</h1>
         <button id = "popup" onclick ="div_show()">Make Payment</button></CENTER>
<!-- Right side div -->
 <img id="fugo" src="images/formget.jpg" alt="Online Form Builder"/></a>
```

I don't have error pop up code.

Answer (score 0):

What you first need to do is hide the form by default:

```
#popupContact {
  display: none;
}
```

Then you need to display the div when your form reaches 50%, by changing the `display` of `#popupContact` in your `if` condition for `frame()`:

```
if (width >= 50) {
  clearInterval(id);
  $('#popupContact').css("display", "block");
}
```

This will make it so that the form automatically becomes visible when the percentage bar reaches 50%. I've created a fiddle showcasing that [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/wb103dps/2/). In the example I've also added in a basic error message.

How you display the form from there is up to you -- if you want to display it as a popup, I recommend looking into either [Bootstrap modals](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) or [jQuery Mobile popups](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_popups.asp).

Hope this helps!